# How do you treat ability bleed damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

In pathfinder the swashbuckler gains the ability to cause ability damage bleed, specifically to physical stats. The heal skill states that first aid deals with bleed doing hit point damage. How is ability bleed damage dealt with? And how long does it take to cure it?

Answer (score 10):

**A DC 15 Heal check or any spell that can cure hit point damage can stop any bleeding.**

The [rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#bleed) for bleed explicitly call out ability damage.

> A creature that is taking bleed damage takes the listed amount of
>   damage at the beginning of its turn. Bleeding can be stopped by a DC
>   15 Heal check or through the application of any spell that cures hit
>   point damage **(even if the bleed is ability damage)**. Some bleed effects
>   cause ability damage or even ability drain. Bleed effects do not stack
>   with each other unless they deal different kinds of damage. When two
>   or more bleed effects deal the same kind of damage, take the worse
>   effect. In this case, ability drain is worse than ability damage.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I was hoping it wasn't so simple to fix.